# Redirect Tomcat 7 console log output to a file (Windows)

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

How do I redirect Tomcat 7 console log output to a file on Windows?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Using `catalina.bat run` can start the tomcat in the current console instead of a new console , so you can redirect all the standard error and standard output stream of this command to a file using

```
catalina.bat run > tomcat.log 2>&1
```

Comment: can you give more explanation?? i can't find catalina.bat in tomcat7 :(

Comment: `catalina.bat` is inside the `bin` folder

Comment: i am using Tomcat 7 so there is no any bat file in bin folder... is there any other way to redirect sysout to log file?

Comment: I am also using tomcat-7.0.26 on the window platform and I can find there are `catalina.bat` inside the `bin` folder

Comment: I don't know why you have one bat file in your tomcat7 , I just downloaded the latest version of tomcat  (7.0.26) for windows from the official site and there are totally 9 bat files in the bin folder

Comment: ohhh my tomcat was installer so why.... now i have downloaded tar :) but what when i use eclipse how pass parameters to tomcat ?

Comment: What does the 2>&1 do?

Comment: This works. But is there a way to limit file size of the tomcat.log in this case and create a new file once this limit is reached or maybe per day basis?

Comment: If you remove  2>&1  it will spit out to both the console and the file (as opposed to only the file)

Comment: catalina.bat is only in the windows-x64.zip at http://www-us.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-7/v7.0.75/bin/apache-tomcat-7.0.75-windows-x64.zip i. It is not in the Tomcat 7 installer at http://www-us.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-7/v7.0.75/bin/apache-tomcat-7.0.75.exe If you want extra debug info make a file called  setenv.bat and put it in the bin DIR and add this line: set "JAVA_OPTS=-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8100 -verbose:class"

Answer (score 6):

To get the Tomcat output and share it::
    1. Make a file " Start_Tomcat.bat " put the below lines in that.

```
cd C:\XXX\apache-tomcat-6.0.20\bin
        catalina.bat run > C:\XXX\apache-tomcat-6.0.20\logs\tomcat1.log 2>&1
```

NOTES:: 
        C:\XXX\apache-tomcat-6.0.20\bin -- is the systems bin address
        " \logs\tomcat1.log 2>&1 " should not change...

```
    Ques:: What does the 2>&1 do?
    Ans:: 2>&1 means output only to file. Without that it would output to both text and console.
```

2. Paste the file in the below location:::
   " C:\XXX\apache-tomcat-6.0.20\bin "
3. Run " Startup.bat " & " Start_Tomcat.bat "
4. You will get " C:\XXX\apache-tomcat-6.0.20\logs\tomcat1.log " . Share the "tomcat1.log" file so others can see your tomcat responses.

Answer (score 0):

File: catalina.bat (in the Tomcat's root \bin directory)

Lines:

```
rem Comment out the line below
rem set _EXECJAVA=start "%TITLE%" %_RUNJAVA%
rem Add the line below instead
set _EXECJAVA=%_RUNJAVA%
```

Next, find the line making the final Java call (add the redirection as below):

```
%_EXECJAVA% %CATALINA_LOGGING_CONFIG% %LOGGING_MANAGER% ... 2>&1 >c:\temp\tomcat.log
```

You will then get your stdout and stderr streams in the file c:\temp\tomcat.log